# Dropdown Menu Hover

Tags: hover, dropdown, nav

I've just decided to learn how to code a few months ago. While practicing dropdown menus, I've came across an issue where the hover effect on a dropdown link is not the same width as the parent link. What am I missing? Thanks for your time.

Here is the CSS that I've tried. What is happening is, I have a color change on the dropdown link, but it isn't cover the full 100%, so, it has the same color before hover on the right side.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #90835a; 


   }

ul li {
   display: inline-block; 
   position: relative;
   font-size: 1.7rem;
 }

ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a ul.dropdown li {
     display: block;
 }

ul li ul.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    background: #90835a;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
 }

ul li a:hover {
    background: #6e6445;
 }

ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
   display: block;
 }
```